# How to sort output of top command based on nice value?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sorting, top, nice

We can use `Shift+p` to sort on basic of **cpu usage**, `Shift+r` to sort on basis of **pid** & `Shift+m` on basis of **memory utilisation**.

How to **sort** output of **top** command based on **nice** value?

Answer (score 0):

1. launch `top`
2. press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to enter menu
3. with key up / key down, highlight `NICE`
4. press <kbd>s</kbd> to sort by
5. press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit menu